# Problem passing boolean value from rich:ComponentControl in order to render rich:menuItems

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

We have the following rich:ComponentControl:

```
<rich:componentControl event="onRowClick" for="ctxMenu" operation="show">
<f:param value="#{item.hasDocuments}" name="hasDocuments" />
</rich:componentControl>
```

The value of #{item.hasDocuments} is being successfully passed from the bean as either true or false.

Here's the contextMenu which is supposed to conditionally show the item:

```
<rich:contextMenu id="ctxMenu" submitMode="ajax" attached="false">
<rich:menuItem ajaxSingle="true" value="View Documents oncomplete="#{rich:component('documentsMenu')}.doShow(event, {})" reRender="documentsMenu" rendered="#{hasDocuments}">
<a4j:actionparam name="selectedApplicationId" value="#{applicationId}" assignTo="#{activeAppsForm.applicationId}" />
</rich:menuItem>
</rich:contextMenu>
```

The problem is that it's always hiding the link, even when {hasDocuments} is true.
My guess is that the value for {hasDocuments} is being treated as string instead of boolean, and therefore rendered will always be false.

Any ideas on how to remedy this problem?

Comment: You should update your question to fix the EL syntax errors to avoid red herrings.

Comment: Updated the question. Any other ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I spent 2 hours fix this issue. But finally it was resolved. Please try following:

```
rendered="#{hasDocuments == 'true'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues.  First of all parameters passed from rich:componentControl are referenced without the hatch in the menuItem.  So you want something like

```
rendered="{hasDocuments}"
```

But that still won't work because of the second issue.  As far as I can tell, parameters passed from rich:componentControl are always passed as Strings.

So try treating hasDocuments as a string. You want something that looks like

```
rendered="#{{hasDocuments}.equals('true')}"
```

HUGE CAVEAT:  This is mainly theory and I see a similar problem in my app that I have not yet worked out.  Please post your answer if you manage to work it out.